# reporting errors when using async with streams node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stream

I am having problems trying to report errors from a function where I read a file and pipe it through csv-parse. What I want to do, is if there is a line that does not have three fields, I want to report back an error - to an async.series call. This first implementation fails as

```
function insertCsvIntoObject(done) {
    fs.createReadStream(inputCsvFilepath)
    .pipe(csvParser)
    .on('data', function (csvRow) {
        console.log('csv row:', csvRow);
        if (csvRow.length !== 3) {
            this.emit('error', "Does this go anywhere?");
        }
    })
    .on('end', function () {
         done(null, "Finished reading through the csv data");
     })
    .on('error', function (err) {
         console.log('errors is now:', csvReadErrors);
         done(new Error('Error reading csv file'), "CSV Parse error");
    });
}
```

This gives a 
Exception: [Error: Callback was already called.] if we have multiple problematic rows in the csv file.

Adding a return before the done

```
return done(new Error('Error reading csv file'), "CSV Parse error");
```

is also no help, since we cannot stop and return from the parent function - insertCsvIntoObject.

furthermore, if there are any error events, the .on('end',..) event never gets fired.

What is the correct way to report errors in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `csv-parse` already emits an error when the number of columns on a line isn't consistent. In other words, you shouldn't have to emit one yourself.

To prevent a callback from being called multiple times, you can use a packaged like [`once`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/once):

```
function insertCsvIntoObject(done) {
  done = once(done);
  ...
};
```

Ideally, you should be able to end the processing after the first error, but I haven't been able to stop the parser from parsing additional records (`this.end()` doesn't seem to work, but perhaps I'm missing something).

Comment: Fair. I ended up using relax_column_count

Comment: Fair. I have discovered that emitting an error does not seem like the best way to return errors to async - since the process abends without the entire file being read. I ended up using relax_column_count to make csv-parse read through to the end (since I might have more checks to ensure that the fields in a row are valid - and I might want to conditionally drop records instead of stopping the whole process), then collected all the errors and send them back through the callback to async in .on('end', ...) Thanks for the tip about once(done) :-)